# Get stored SSIS Package's Connection string information

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012, ssis-2008

I have 100s of packages in my current production server. I have to check the server and DB details of all these stored SSIS packages. The packages are available under Server>Stored Packages>File System.

The manual way is to download each package and check the connection managers. Is there any other easy way to do this?

Comment: If you had stored the connection strings in .config files you could check those instead, but you'd still be checking 100's of files, so I don't know if I'd call it "easy".

Comment: SSIS package or *.dtsx file is basically an XML file. If you open that file in textpad you would see XML tags and the `<DTS:ConnectionManagers>` tag would have all connection objects used in that package. Now you can develop a script which can go thru all 100s of files and search for text between the start and end tag of `<DTS:ConnectionManagers>` that would give you the connection strings.
You could use .net (C#/VB) to develop that script, or you can make another SSIS pacakge with 
script task which can run thru all 100s of XMLs.